# Android Camera no save in specific folder [MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA]

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, image

I'm a problem when I using the MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA in the Intent. The camera starts correctly but it doesn't save the files in my specific folder "/photo". But when I use the MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE it works fine, but I can't use this because it take only one photo each time. 
I need the camera starts and the user takes many photos. After he closes the camera and all photos are saved in my specific folder.

Thanks for your help.

Regards,

Marcelo

Source code:

```
public void startCamera() {     
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = createImageFile();
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        file = null;
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);            
    }
    activity.startActivity(takePictureIntent);
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX;
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/photo/", imageFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA` This intent does not support activity results or specific intent file outputs. This intent is designed to simply open the camera.  The functionality you seek does not exist natively in Android.

Comment: I want to allow user to take either photo / video and then catch result , Is it possible with Intent or i need to write implementation of Camera with surface view ?

Comment: @Jack ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE can save image/video in user defined location.